# Lower bound for norm on a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(V,||\cdot||)$ be a finite dimensional normed vector space. If $\lbrace e_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ is a basis we can write $$x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i$$

For any $x\in V$ and $x_i\in \mathbb{F}$. Let $M=\max_i |x_i|$.

**Given that $||e_i||$ are normalized to 1, is it true that $M\leq ||x||$ for an arbitrary norm $||\cdot||$ on $V$?**

I couldn't think of any counter examples for the $p$ norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I wasn't able to prove it either.

Comment: What we can say is:  there exist positive constants $A,B$ so that $A\|x\|  \le \max_i |x_i| \le B\|x\|$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ consider the norm $\|(x,y)\|=\max\{|x|,|x+y|\}$ and $e_1=(1,0),e_2=(0,1)$. Then $\|e_k\|=1$ $(k=1,2)$. Now
$$
\|(-1,2)\| = 1, \quad (-1,2)=-e_1+2e_2, \quad M=2.
$$